# Can't retrieve the 390-characters text record added to 1k Mifare Classic tag

Tags: c++, arduino, nfc, ndef, pn532

I add a text a 390-characters long text record to 1k Mifare Classic card, I can write
it successfully, but records are empty when reading it. I
use NDEF library with PN532 and Ardunio uno.

my code :

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <PN532_I2C.h>
#include <PN532.h>
#include <NfcAdapter.h>

PN532_I2C pn532_i2c(Wire);
NfcAdapter nfc = NfcAdapter(pn532_i2c);

void setup()
{
Serial.begin(115200);
Serial.println("Serial Start");
nfc.begin();
Serial.println("NFC Start");
}

void loop()
{
if (nfc.tagPresent()) {
NfcTag tag = nfc.read();
tag.print();
}
if (nfc.tagPresent()) {
NdefMessage message = NdefMessage();
message.addTextRecord("denemedenemedenemedenemedenemedenemedenemedenemedenemedenemedenemedenemedenemedenemeden");

    bool   success = nfc.write(message);
    if (success)
    {
        Serial.println("Write Success");
    }
    else
    {
        Serial.println("Error");
    }
}
}
```

I use the example shown [here](https://github.com/don/NDEF/issues/53) but it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you formatted the card for NDef in another App before you try and write the NDef message? A lot of card types need formatting before you can write Ndef data to them and a 1k Mifare Classic card does need formatting.

Comment: @Andrew yes formatted card to ndef but not working

Answer (score 0):

You code for adding a text "record" into the tag is correct. The reading from the tag for the message payload however is not. It take a little bit more to get to the "record". The `nfc.read()` return a tag object which consists of a message object, which could consists of multiple records, and within each record, it has the payload length and payload (which is the text node you added), some parsing is required to get the data you wrote into it.

Please noted that the data are stored with a prefix that indicating the charset used for encoding the record, I add the code to discard the prefix, the record is stored in `byte`, it need to be cast to `char` before `Serial.print()`.

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <PN532_I2C.h>
#include <PN532.h>
#include <NfcAdapter.h>

PN532_I2C pn532_i2c(Wire);
NfcAdapter nfc = NfcAdapter(pn532_i2c);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Serial Start");
  nfc.begin();
  Serial.println("NFC Start");
}

void loop()
{
  // read from the tag for NDEF message payload
  char tagMsg[100]={'\0'};  // make sure this is longer than your added text
  if (nfc.tagPresent()) {
    NfcTag tag = nfc.read();
    if (tag.hasNdefMessage()) {    // an empty tag won't have any message
       NdefMessage message = tag.getNdefMessage();
       NdefRecord record = message.getRecord(0);  // only get the first records
       int payloadLength = record.getPayloadLength();
       uint8_t payload[payloadLength];
       record.getPayload(payload);
       // drop the first 3 bytes, which specify the language e.g. en=English
       for (uint8_t s = 3, d=0; s < payloadLength; s++, d++) {
         tagMsg[d] = (char)payload[s];
       }
       Serial.println(tagMsg);  //this will be the text msg you added
    }
  }

  // add a text message to the NDEF tag
  if (nfc.tagPresent()) {
    NdefMessage message = NdefMessage();
    message.addTextRecord("denemedenemedenemedenemedenemedenemedenemedenemedenemedenemedenemedenemedenemedenemeden");

    if (nfc.write(message))
    {
        Serial.println("Write Success");
    }
    else
    {
        Serial.println("Error");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, the code written above is for reading but my question is about writing. I need to write 390 characters inside the card